# EF Core One-to-Many Linq query

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework-core, relational-database

I have a one-to-many relationship between two entities, and need to query a combination of those two entities.

The one is a **File** model:

```
 public class FileMetadata
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
        public int FileContentId { get; set; }
        public FileContent Content { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
    }
```

And the other is a **Tag** model:

```
public class FileTag
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int FileMetadataId { get; set; }
        public FileMetadata Metadata { get; set; }
    }
```

The nature of the relationship, is that a **File** can have one-to-many **Tags**. What I need to do, is implement a search method, that can search the contents (description, name etc.) of a File, but *also*, search on all the Tags for that File. This is where the issue is, I can't find an *efficient* way to do that.

This is what I have done so far, it gives me the expected result, but, it is not efficient:

```
 public async Task<ServiceResponse<FileSearchResult>> SearchFileMetaData(string searchText, int page, float resultsPerPage)
    {
        var pageCount = Math.Ceiling((await FindFilesBySearchText(searchText)).Count / resultsPerPage);

        //Add tags to descriptions
        var extendedFiles = _context.Files.ToList();
        var tags = _context.FileTags.ToList();

        foreach (var file in extendedFiles)
        {
            var thisFilesTags = tags.Where(t => t.FileMetadataId == file.Id).ToList();
            foreach (var tag in thisFilesTags)
            {
                file.Description += tag.Text;
            }
        }

        //Search files with metadata matching the search text.
        var files = extendedFiles
                        .Where(f => f.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower())
                        || f.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()))
                        .Skip((page - 1) * (int)resultsPerPage)
                        .Take((int)resultsPerPage)
                        .ToList();

        var response = new ServiceResponse<FileSearchResult>
        {
            Data = new FileSearchResult
            {
                Files = files,
                ThisPageNumber = page,
                TotalPages = (int)Math.Floor(pageCount)
            }
        };
        return response;
    }
```

I am getting *all* the files and tags from the database, looping to build up the description field with that File entity's tags, then performing the Linq operation to filter on the search text.

How can I still get the expected result, but improve the performance, but not getting unnecessary records?

Also, can this be solved with a better Linq query, that joins those two entities? Or, does the relationships/tables need to be redefined?

Comment: Aft first `var pageCount = ` is suspicious, how products are related files?

Comment: Also, "contains" queries can be problematic in databases. You will be relying on the database setting for case sensitivity (i.e. collation), and databases cannot use the index to check if a string contains another. It can only check if there is an exact match, or the stored string starts with some other string. At least if you want to do it efficiently.

Comment: @JonasH Of course, it is actually one-to-many, I will edit and change the description of the problem.

Comment: @JonasH Thanks for the tip about the "contains" queries, it makes sense. What is the accepted best practice to approach such a problem though? How would one efficiently extract entities that have properties that match a particular string?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Correct. That was an incorrect naming on my part. Also, looking into it now, I see that there is a bug in that statement, as this is the code within that function:

`return await _context.Files
                            .Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower())
                            || p.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()))
                            .ToListAsync();`

This of course, does not make sense as it does not take the tags into account, when calculating the number of pages. Just changed it to `FindFilesBySearchText`

Comment: There are no simple answers. There are dedicated search engines for full text search. Some database specific extension that might help. You could also just use "StartsWith" instead of "contain", or just accept a full table scan if there are not to many entries.

Comment: @JonasH Are there any database extensions/search engines that you could recommend? Or point me in the right direction in terms of research? I expect the File table to have a large amount of records, therefore efficiency is important. But, I should also be able to perform a search on those entities. I am using MariaDB in a cloud VM, with Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 7.0.0

Comment: Sorry, I have no specific recommendations. Other than to try the simplest solution first. Just make sure to test with however many items you think you will have. Estimating performance can be really difficult, so it is best to test until you find a solution that works well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query. It tries to filter out files before materialization. For sure it is not ideal solution, `Contains` performs full table scan, which may affect performance if table is really big.

```cs
public async Task<ServiceResponse<FileSearchResult>> SearchFileMetaData(string searchText, int page, float resultsPerPage)
{
    searchText = searchText.ToLower();

    var filesQuery = _context.Files
        .Where(f => f.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchText)
            || f.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchText)
            || _context.FileTags.Any(t => t.FileMetadataId == f.Id && t.Text.ToLower().Contains(searchText))
        );

    var pageCount = Math.Ceiling((await filesQuery.CountAsync()) / resultsPerPage);

    var files = filesQuery
        .Skip((page - 1) * (int)resultsPerPage)
        .Take((int)resultsPerPage)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .ToList();

    var response = new ServiceResponse<FileSearchResult>
    {
        Data = new FileSearchResult
        {
            Files = files,
            ThisPageNumber = page,
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Floor(pageCount)
        }
    };

    return response;
}
```